# WC_Shipping_Method extended, calculate_shipping no longer being called?? Ideas on where to look?

Tags: woocommerce, extends

HELP!!!  Code that used to work no longer works!  I've been pulling my hair out for two weeks trying to find this bug.  Can someone point me at it, please??? Any suggestions or ideas will be appreciated!!!

The code is supposed to reach out to a remote supplier's server, retrieve available shipping methods and costs and return them.  Now, that code doesn't even appear to be getting called. Instead, I get the message "No shipping options were found for " followed by the shipping address.

This message is coded in line 83 of
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php

```
sprintf( esc_html__( 'No shipping options were found for %s.', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '<strong>' . esc_html( $formatted_destination ) . '</strong>' ),
```

My code extends the WC_Shipping_Method. It appears that the calculate_shipping function isn't being called any more.  It used to work fine.  I'm sure something was changed, but I have no idea when or where. I added an echo statement as the first executable line in the function, but it never executes.

I do know that the constructor is being executed.  I added an echo comment to it and it gets printed to the screen in several pages.

I don't know if I have a corrupted file, if a plugin broke it, or what.  Still investigating plugins, but not optimistic.

This is coded in a child theme's function.php file. I'll be happy to add more info on request.

Any ideas??????

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_alpha_shipping');
function add_alpha_shipping($methods) {
    $methods['alpha_shipping'] = 'alpha_Shipping_Method';
    return $methods;
}

class alpha_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {

    public function __construct($instance_id = 0) {
        $this->id = 'alpha_shipping';
        $this->instance_id = absint($instance_id);
        $this->domain = 'alpha_shipping';
        $this->method_title = __('Alpha Ship', $this->domain);
        $this->method_description = __('Shipping method to be used when drop shipping from alpha', $this->domain);
        $this->title = __('Alpha Ship', $this->domain);
        $this->supports = array(
            'shipping-zones',
            'instance-settings',
            'instance-settings-modal',
        );
    
        $this->instance_form_fields = array(
            'enabled' => array(
            'title'         => __( 'Enable/Disable' ),
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'label'         => __( 'Enable this shipping method' ),
            'default'       => 'yes',
        ),
            'title' => array(
            'title'         => __( 'Method Title' ),
            'type'          => 'text',
            'description'   => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.' ),
            'default'       => __( '' ),
            'desc_tip'      => true
        )
    );

        $this->enabled = $this->get_option( 'enabled' );
        $this->title   = __('MS', $this->domain);

        add_action('woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
    }


    public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
                echo "Entering calculate_shipping function. <br>";
    
        //a lengthy code block follows, but this doesn't appear to be getting called at all. 
    }
```

I have no idea when or where it went bad.  Backups aged out, so I can't backtrack.